# How to align check box on the right side in CheckedtextView

Tags: android, xml, text, checkbox

I have an XML layout and I want to make the CheckBox align to the right side.
Only the CheckBox should be on the right side not the text.

How can I do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <CheckedTextView
             android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code is working for me

```
 <CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/checkedTextView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#000000,"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="CheckedTextView" />
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that this should go inside a `RelativeLayout` and **not** a `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `android:gravity="center_vertical|right"` inside your CheckedTextView element.

Answer (score 0):

Change to :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this is causing problems on a wide range of devices :/ I am using two views for this now, one is a custom made `ImageView` which has an internal checked state that changes on image click and has getters and setters for that too. The other view is a simple `TextView`. Now I put both of them into a `RelativeLayout` and set alignParentRight on the `ImageView` and tell the `TextView` to be to the right of the image and fill the parent in width and also be in a vertical center.

Prior to this I was using `drawableRight="@drawable/..."` on the CheckBox

Answer (score -1):

Replace this line:

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

with

```
android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
```